# Date/time field cant be selected in scheduled action in Process Builder

Tags: formula, process-builder, formula-field, datetime

I have a custom object with a custom date/time formula field. When I try to select this field in the processbuilder the field does not show up. Am I missing something?

See image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Process Builder can't see fields that you can't see. You will need to go to the formula field, click on Set Field Level Security, and check the field as Visible. Note that having the field hidden won't hinder the ability for the Process to execute (it runs in System mode), but the Process Builder itself runs in User mode.

Comment: Thanks, overlooked that one a little bit embarrasing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Time-based action - these can only reference certain Datetime fields as [per doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=0). See if your custom formula Datetime field falls into one of the restricted use cases:

> Time triggers can’t reference the following:
>
> DATE or DATETIME fields
> containing automatically derived functions, such as TODAY or NOW.
>
> Formula fields that include related-object merge fields.

If you think about it, SFDC has to monitor the SObject for changes to know when to remove the time trigger; but formula fields that depend on NOW() or TODAY() or cross-object fields would only be calculated on retrieval of the object - but nothing is telling SFDC when to do this work.